# issue with SSL configure for Mysql and Java

Tags: java, mysql, ssl

I am trying to use a SSL connection  for mysql so that I can use it in a Java application. I followed the instructions  which I found in 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-ssl-files-using-openssl.html. 
The setting   I was doing it for my local system (Window 7 , 64bit ,  Server version: 5.1.72-community MySQL Community Server).

The following Script I executed
**openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 90 

openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key-compatible.pem**

After that I have added/mapped the certificate details in my.ini file

**ssl-cert=C:\cert\cert.pem 

ssl-key=C:\cert\key-compatible.pem** 
Then restarted  mysql service after than  I could able to see  certificate by execute the command  in mysql
show global variables like '%ssl%';

[image]

But when I log in with my client and view the status, it  is not listing  a cipher on the SSL line instead it is showing as not in use

[image]

IS there anything  missing in configuration  for SSL ?

Thanks & Regards
Giby Alex

Comment: I don't see any ca cert being specified according to your description. Perhaps that's the missing part?

Comment: is the CA part required ?  i have skipped ias it  was connection is setting in my localhost system

Comment: I am not sure (docs don't mention it clearly). But worth a try. I guess the CA cert will also be self signed even on localhost. Have you tried this helper script? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ssl-rsa-setup.html